# Replace array by specific element value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to replace my main array elements by 'employee_id'. 
I already tried **array_replace_recursive()** function But It replaces arrays by the default index value.

> $merged = array_replace_recursive($empList, $getworkedHrs,
>   $getErrAttnds);

The arrays look like this:
$empList

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '254',
        'emp_name' => 'Mary McDonald',
        'worked_days' => 0,
        'worked_hours' => 0,
        'error_attendance' => 0,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '255',
        'emp_name' => 'Anthony Coffman',
        'worked_days' => 0,
        'worked_hours' => 0,
        'error_attendance' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '316',
        'emp_name' => 'cheth aruno',
        'worked_days' => 0,
        'worked_hours' => 0,
        'error_attendance' => 0,
      ),
   )
```

2nd Array: $getworkedHrs

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'employee_id' => '254',
    'worked_days' => '22',
    'worked_hours' => '7.0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'employee_id' => '255',
    'worked_days' => '8',
    'worked_hours' => '7.0',
  ),
)
```

3rd array : $getErrAttnds

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'employee_id' => '316',
    'error_attendance' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Expected Result Array:

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '254',
        'emp_name' => 'Mary McDonald',
        'worked_days' => 22,
        'worked_hours' => 7.0,
        'error_attendance' => 0,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '255',
        'emp_name' => 'Anthony Coffman',
        'worked_days' => 8,
        'worked_hours' => 7.0,
        'error_attendance' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'employee_id' => '316',
        'emp_name' => 'cheth aruno',
        'worked_days' => 0,
        'worked_hours' => 0,
        'error_attendance' => 1,
      ),
   )
```

Comment: Print_r is good if we just want to look at the arrays, use var_export and update all your arrays. That way we don't have to retype everything by hand

Comment: Sure. I changed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest solution is to merge them in two foreach.

First make the main array associative so that it's easier to get the correct employee.

Then loop the arrays and copy the values.

```
$empList = array_column($empList, null, 'employee_id');

foreach($getworkedHrs as $entry){
    $empList[$entry['employee_id']]['worked_days'] = $entry['worked_days'];
    $empList[$entry['employee_id']]['worked_hours'] = $entry['worked_hours'];
}

foreach($getErrAttnds as $entry){
    $empList[$entry['employee_id']]['error_attendance'] = $entry['error_attendance'];
}

var_export($empList);
```

https://3v4l.org/gIXP6